# Bounding a sinusoid of unity amplitude with third order harmonics?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, proof-writing

I am trying to find a proof for why or why not this is possible:

I would like to take a generic sine wave, $y = \sin(x)$ and bound it between $\pm 0.5$, only through the use of third order harmonics.  In other words, I want to know if this is ever true:
$$-0.5\leq\sin(x) + a_3\sin(3x +\phi_3) + a_9\sin(9x+\phi_9) +\cdots +a_{3^n}\sin(3^nx+\phi_{3^n}) \leq0.5$$

I know that a solution could be found piecewise, but could a solution exist with constant $a_k$ and $\phi_k$?

Thanks for the help.